# Why or when would a Map.get(..) need synchronization?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, synchronization

This is a code snippet from collections's [`SynchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29). My question is not specific to the code snippet below - but a generic one: Why does a get operation need synchronization?

```
public V get(Object key) {
    synchronized (mutex) {return m.get(key);}
}
```

Comment: Because it may be accessed by multiple threads at the same moment.

Comment: Yeah, but to make question more specific, in which part of code would that be an issue ? eg: would it be during hashing ? where would threads conflict during this call ? will they even or will they not ?

Comment: Imagine two threads: T1 constantly gets the values from the map and T2  puts/replace data on the map. Both threads run in parallel. Having a key K, T2 will refresh value for K at the same exact moment T1 is retrieving the value of K. Which one should execute first? Which value should T1 retrieve, the old value or the new one?

Comment: lucid explanation. Good point sir.

Answer (score 2):

If your threads are only ever `get`ting from the `Map`, the synchronization is not needed. In this case it might be a good idea to express this fact by using an immutable map, like the one from the [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) libraries, this protects you at compile time from accidentally modifying the map anyway.

The trouble begins when multiple threads are reading and modifying the map, because the internal structure of, e.g. the [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) implementation from the Java standard libraries is not prepared for that. In this case you can either wrap an external serialization layer around that map, like

- using the `synchronized` keyword,
- slightly safer would be to use a [`SynchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29), because then you can't forget the `synchonized` keyword everywhere it's needed,
- protect the map using a [`ReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html), which would allow multiple concurrently reading threads (which is fine)
- switch to an [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) altogether, which is prepared for being accessed by multiple threads.

But coming back to you original question, *why is the synchronization needed in the first place*: This is a bit hard to tell without looking at the code of the class. Possibly it would break when the `put` or `remove` from one thread causes the bucket count to change, which would cause a reading thread to see too many / too few elements because the resize is not finished yet. Maybe something completely different, I don't know and it's not really important because the exact reason(s) why it is unsafe can change at any time with a new Java release. The important fact is only *that* it is not supported and your code will likely blow up one or another way at runtime.

Comment: +1 for all the options to handle this problem. Altogether with `ConcurrentHashMap`, I would recommend reviewing classes in [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package for concurrent programming.

Answer (score 0):

If the table gets resized in the middle of the call to `get()`, it could potentially look in the wrong bucket and return null incorrectly.

Consider the steps that happen in `m.get()`:

1. A hash is calculated for the key.
2. The current length of the table (the buckets in the HashMap) is read.
3. This length is used to calculate the correct bucket to get from the table.
4. The bucket is retrieved and the entries in the bucket are walked until a match is found or until the end of the bucket is reached.

If another thread changes the map and causes the table to be resized in between 2 & 3, the wrong bucket could be used to look for the entry, potentially giving an incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why synchronization is needed in a concurrent environment is, that java operations aren't atomic. This means that a single java operation like `counter++` causes the underlaying VM to execute more than one machine operation.

1. Read value
2. Increment value
3. Write value

While those three operations are performed, another thread called **T2** may be invoked and read the old value e.g `10` of that variable. **T1** increments that value und writes the value `11` back. But T2 has read value `10`! In cas that **T2** should also increment this value, the result stays the same, namely `11` instead of `12`.

The synchronisation will avoid such concurrent errors.

**T1:**

1. Set synchronizer token
2. Read value
3. *Another thread T2 was invoked and tries to read the value. But since the synchronizer token was already set, T2 has to wait.*
4. Increment value
5. Write value
6. Remove synchronizer token

**T2:**

1. Set synchronizer token
2. Read value
3. Increment value
4. Write value
5. Remove synchronizer token

Answer (score 0):

By synchronising the get method you are forcing the thread to cross the memory barrier and read the value from the main memory. If you wouldn't synchronise the get method then the JVM takes liberties to apply underlying optimisations that might result in that thread reading blissfully unaware a stale value stored in registers and caches.